# How to verify with Jasmine that a module called a sub-module method with correct arguments

Tags: jasmine

The following test spec simulates calling a module that writes some content to the file system.  Internally it uses fs to do that.  I want to make sure fs.writeFile() was called with correct parameters.  However, the toHaveBeenCalledWith() doesn't seem to work with a generic Function argument.  Any ideas on how to make toHaveBeenCalledWith work as I expect?

Test Spec:

```
var fs = {
    writeFile: function (arg1, arg2, cb){}
}

var writeContent = {
    toFS: function (){
        var path = "some/calculated/path";
        var content = "some content";
        fs.writeFile(path, content, function(){})
    }
}

describe("writeContent", function() {

    var writeFileSpy = null;

    beforeEach(function() {

        writeFileSpy = jasmine.createSpy('writeFileSpy');
        spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').and.callFake(writeFileSpy);
    });

    it("can call spy with callback", function() {

        writeContent.toFS();

        expect(writeFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("some/calculated/path", "some content", Function);
    });

});
```

Results:

```
  Message:
    Expected spy writeFileSpy to have been called with [ 'some/calculated/path', 'some content', Function ] but actual calls were [ 'some/calculated/path', 'some content', Function ].
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question :-)  Just needed to enclose Function in jasmine.any() as in:

```
expect(writeFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("some/calculated/path", "some content", jasmine.any(Function));
```